# ¿Pedir perdón o pedir permiso? Consideraciones de desempeño

Tags: python, excepciones

La famosa frase de [Grace Hopper](https://es.wikiquote.org/wiki/Grace_Hopper):

> Es más fácil pedir perdón que pedir permiso

La cual es popular dentro de la comunidad de programadores, hace que me pregunte si esto aplica en el código para Python, muchas veces me siento inclinado (por facilidad) en usar excepciones. Consideren el siguiente caso:

```
lista = []

# Pedir perdón
try:
    elemento = lista[0]
except IndexError:
    elemento = None

# Pedir permiso
elemento = None
if len(lista) > 1:
    elemento = lista[0]
```

En resumen lo que quiero saber es, ¿existe alguna diferencia de desempeño en Python al usar una o la otra?

Pregunto esto ya que he escuchado de un amigo que en Java, por ejemplo, es costoso usar el bloque `try {} catch {}` debido a una serie de procesos realizados para llenar el stack trace lo cual hace que pienses bien antes de usarlos. ¿Ocurre lo mismo para Python?

Comment: creo que el titulo no es muy especifico, deberias editarlo y ser mas acertado

Comment: usar un try catch solo es mas costoso cuando se hace uso del mismo, osea cuando captura la excepcion, pero eso no quiere decir que llenes el programa de try saludos

Comment: ¡Buena pregunta! Parecido en SOen: [“Ask forgiveness not permission” - explain](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12265451/1983854) y [Why is it “Easier to ask forgiveness than permission” in python, but not in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6092992/1983854). Nótese que incluso el [glosario de Python](https://docs.python.org/2.7/glossary.html) lo menciona.

Comment: Para el manejo de excepciones, es necesario guardar el entorno de ejecución antes de intentar recuperar el control. Es bastante costoso, pero no más que lanzar un hilo de ejecución, algo que hacen los sistemas operativos bastante eficientemente.

De hecho, frente al "pedir perdón" o "pedir permiso", existe otra posibilidad: crear un nuevo "entorno de ejecución"

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Depende de cual sea el **objetivo del programa**, si tu objetivo es rendimiento (**en tiempo**), un **bloque try-catch** se vuelve costoso,en comparacion con un **if**, cuando este captura una excepción.

Pero si lo que buscas es **robustez**, siempre es preferible un buen manejo de excepciones. Además un buen manejo de excepciones ayuda a la interpratación del codigo desde el punto de vista lógico

Acá te dejo un ejemplo del tiempo de procesamiento de cpu utilizado por cada bloque, se puede observar que el bloque if utiliza menos tiempo de cpu cuando el try captura la excepción en comparacion con el bloque condicional

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import time

lista = []

def bloque():
  try:
    elemento = lista[0]
  except IndexError:
    elemento = None

def bloque_if():
  elemento = None
if len(lista) > 1:
    elemento = lista[0]


# tiempo de procesamiento
t0 = time.clock()
bloque()
print time.clock() - t0, "seg bloque try-catch "

t0 = time.clock()
bloque_if()
print time.clock() - t0, "seg bloque if"
```

Comment: Con respecto al rendimiento de Python, no estoy comparando su performance con otro lenguaje, yo se que al ser un lenguaje interpretado tiene su costo, la pregunta va mas por el tema de manejo de excepciones

Comment: Cuando hablas de desempeño, estás hablando de rendimiento

Comment: Santi, mencionas que el bloque try-catch es costoso, tienes alguna referencia a eso? Es mas costoso no usarlo?

Comment: No estoy muy familiarizado con Python, pero, si entiendo bien, una excepción es un *objeto* que guarda, entre otras cosas, las condiciones que generan el error en tiempo de ejecución y la pila de llamadas (*stack trace*) que llevaron al error. Si esto es (al menos en principio) correcto, al generarse una excepción se utilizan recursos adicionales (memoria) para crear y guardar el objeto. Lo cual, sólo por uso de recursos, hace que usar excepciones sea más "costoso" que validar las expresiones a mano. Sin embargo, desde el punto de vista de "limpieza", el uso correcto de excepciones es mejor.

Comment: @Santi92 gracias, adradezco tu esfuerzo en ayudarme a encontrar una respuesta. Saludos!

Answer (score 5):

Considero que la respuesta de @Santi92 es la correcta, la mejor forma es hacer un tipo de benchmark para conocer el resultado pero no con una iteración sino con varios miles.

Sin embargo, con el afán de compartir el conocimiento sobre este tema, encontré lo siguiente usando el módulo `timeit` de Python:

```
import timeit

statements=["""\
try:
    b = 10/a
except ZeroDivisionError:
    pass""",
"""\
if a:
    b = 10/a""",
"b = 10/a"]

for a in (1,0):
    for s in statements:
        t = timeit.Timer(stmt=s, setup='a={}'.format(a))
        print("a = {}\n{}".format(a,s))
        print("%.2f usec/pass\n" % (1000000 * t.timeit(number=100000)/100000))
```

Resultado:

```
a = 1
try:
    b = 10/a
except ZeroDivisionError:
    pass
0.25 usec/pass

a = 1
if a:
    b = 10/a
0.29 usec/pass

a = 1
b = 10/a
0.22 usec/pass

a = 0
try:
    b = 10/a
except ZeroDivisionError:
    pass
0.57 usec/pass

a = 0
if a:
    b = 10/a
0.04 usec/pass

a = 0
b = 10/a
ZeroDivisionError: int division or modulo by zero
```

Con lo que se puede llegar a la conclusión de que "pedir perdón" es más rápido que "pedir permiso" siempre y cuando la excepción no sea levantada. Lo cual afirma lo que algunos mencionaban en los comentarios.

### Referencias:

- [Cost of exception handlers in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2522005/cost-of-exception-handlers-in-python/2522013#2522013) (respuesta de [Tim Pietzcker](https://stackoverflow.com/users/20670/tim-pietzcker))
- [How fast are exceptions?](https://docs.python.org/2/faq/design.html#how-fast-are-exceptions)

Comment: +1 por copiar el código que mide el tiempo de ejecución, muy relevante.

Answer (score 1):

yo comente por ahi que el try solo es mas lento en rasgos generales cuando este captura la excepcion este es un ejemplo:

```
import timeit

   timeit.timeit(setup="a=1;b=1", stmt="a/b") 
   0.06870104099999708
```

. esta parte que se muestra a continuacion es la interesante (el try es mas rapido que el if cuando no salta este)

```
   timeit.timeit(setup="a=1;b=1", stmt="try:\n a/b\nexcept ZeroDivisionError:\n pass")
   0.08890565000001516  
   timeit.timeit(setup="a=1;b=1", stmt="if b!=0:\n a/b")
   0.10628072599996585
```

.esta parte que se muestra a continuacion es de relleno pues el try salta y adenas efectua la operacion por eso salta ja, y en el if pues solo compara de ahi que sea un mas rapido

```
   timeit.timeit(setup="a=1;b=0", stmt="try:\n a/b\nexcept ZeroDivisionError:\n pass")
   0.3348089790000017    
   timeit.timeit(setup="a=1;b=0", stmt="if b!=0:\n a/b")
   0.042805305999991106
```

Answer (score 0):

Tomando tal cual tu analogía, 
tenemos dos verdades, hasta que alguien me demuestre lo contrario.

Sólo sé pide perdón si te has equivocado, sin embargo, SIEMPRE deberías 
pedir permiso, por cortersía ;).

Ahora bien, tomando en cuenta esto, porque mencionar cual es más
fácil?, vamos que manejar excepciones tal cual lo planteas, no es más dificil 
o más fácil que validar la información por dar un ejemplo.

Para mí esa sería la regla, siempre o siempre que el tiempo te lo permita pedir
permiso, y sólo se debería pedir perdón en casos que de momento están
fuera de tu análisis preliminar.

Comment: Según tengo entendido las computadoras no responden diferente si se les trata o no con cortesía. Si no es así, por favor, agrega un ejemplo o referencia.

Answer (score 0):

Lo mejor en "performance" es:

Si nunca te vas a equivocar o casi nunca, pide perdon, y no pierdas tiempo en pedir permiso.

Si te equivocas muchas veces, pide permiso, que te costara menos que pedir varios perdones.

Y ten en cuenta que 1 millon de permisos consume mucho más que un perdon.

Pero que un 1 millon de permisos consume muchisimo menos que medio millon de perdones.

Answer (score -2):

En tu caso, especularía, cual es la tendencia de tu código. En cuestiones de *performance*, es mas barato pedir perdón por que se hace la suposición que el sistema esta bien analizado, diseñado y codificado.

Esto es muy parecido al concepto de la [predicción de saltos](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/147/531).

Si notas que el código lanza mas excepciones que seguir el flujo programado, entonces debes pedir permiso cada vez que quieras hacer la operación que lanza la excepción.

Ahora, si la operación no tiende a lanzar excepciones, entonces pido perdón.

Comment: Pedir perdón es más costo que pedir permiso, muchas veces (caso java, c#,vb, sql, etc). creo que confundes las analogías de pedir perdón y permiso.

Comment: @JuanRuizdeCastilla no me confundo los términos. Pedir perdón es cuando el código lanza un error y es capturado como una excepción. Pedir permiso es verificar, con anterioridad, si voy a cometer un error de lógica en el código.

Comment: No es contradictorio esto "Ahora, si la operación no tiende a lanzar excepciones, entonces pido perdón", según lo que dices?.

Comment: @JuanRuizdeCastilla No tiene nada de contradictorio. Si yo se, de antemano, que es muy posible que una operación que vaya a lanzar una excepción o un error, entonces pido _permiso_ para evitar que tener que pagar el costo de capturar esa excepción. Ahora, si la operación no lanza excepciones o tiene una tendencia muy baja a que lance errores por que es muy excepcional el caso que lo haga, entonces pido _perdón_ y pago el costo de capturar la excepción por que seria mas costoso estar verificando constantemente si me salgo de la lógica de la operación.