# Python ¿Qué es mas eficiente if not == o if !=?

Tags: python

¿Cuál es la diferencia entre las siguientes líneas:

```
if not x == 'val':
```

y

```
if x != 'val':
```

¿Existe alguna forma de comprobar si una es más eficiente que la otra?

o, ¿tal vez sería mejor el siguiente bloque?:

```
if x == 'val':
    pass
else:
```

Answer (score 29, accepted):

#### Desensamblado

Si usamos el [desensamblador para Python (`dis`)](https://docs.python.org/2/library/dis.html), vemos que los 3 compilan a la misma cantidad de instrucciones, y sólo se diferencian en el `POP_JUMP_IF_TRUE` o `POP_JUMP_IF_FALSE`

```
!=
              0 LOAD_FAST                0 (x)
              3 LOAD_CONST               1 ('val')
              6 COMPARE_OP               3 (!=)
              9 POP_JUMP_IF_FALSE       15
```

---

```
not ==
              0 LOAD_FAST                0 (x)
              3 LOAD_CONST               1 ('val')
              6 COMPARE_OP               2 (==)
              9 POP_JUMP_IF_TRUE        15
```

---

```
== else
              0 LOAD_FAST                0 (x)
              3 LOAD_CONST               1 ('val')
              6 COMPARE_OP               2 (==)
              9 POP_JUMP_IF_FALSE       15
```

[<kbd>Demo en ideone</kbd>](http://ideone.com/CopERU)

---

#### Profile

Usando [cProfile](https://docs.python.org/3/library/profile.html), podemos medir el tiempo de ejecución y realizar un *benchmark*:

```
          ncalls  tottime  percall  cumtime  percall filename:lineno(function)
not ==   5000000    1.589    0.000    1.589    0.000 ./prog.py:8(en)
== else  5000000    1.562    0.000    1.562    0.000 ./prog.py:12(ee)
!=       5000000    1.508    0.000    1.508    0.000 ./prog.py:4(ne)
```

Ordenados de más lento a más rápido, podemos ver que:

- `if not x == 'val'` es el más lento.
- `if x == 'val'` + `else` es ~**1.7%** más rápido.
- `if x != 'val'` es ~**3.6%** aún más rápido.
- Entre el más lento y el más rápido sólo ahorramos 81ms / 5 millones de comparaciones.

[<kbd>Demo en ideone</kbd>](http://ideone.com/5ntPwq)

<sub>* O [acá](http://ideone.com/TE9a39) dejo un ejemplo más complejo para comparar casos verdaderos y falsos con strings aleatorios.</sub>

---

#### Conclusión

La condición `if x != 'val'` es levemente más eficiente.

Sin embargo, en mi opinión, la diferencia no es lo suficientemente significativa como para cambiar el estilo a la hora de codificar. Prefiero a toda costa que el código sea lo más sencillo de leer, y sólo pensaría en tener este resultado en cuenta en cálculos extremadamente intensivos que requieran ahorrar toda fracción de segundo posible.

Comment: Felicidades por la respuesta, pero que diferencia hay en leer if not x == `val` con if x != 'val', lo digo porque me parece que la instrucción más rápida es sin duda la que se entiende mejor, por ser muy común entre lenguajes de programación.

Comment: También creo que a modo general es más sencillo leer `!=`, pero me imagino que habrá situaciones en un código más complejo donde, por ejemplo, se asigne `condicion = (x == 'val')`, y más adelante se utilice `if not condicion`. Por supuesto, todo depende del estilo propio de cada programador. El punto que quise marcar es que con diferencias no tan significativas, conviene priorizar una opción que aporte más legibilidad al código.

Comment: ¿Podríamos ver el código de tu benchmark?

Comment: @JoseAntonioDuraOlmos está en la respuesta, haciendo click en "**Demo en ideone**". Es el uso típico de cProfile, por lo que no consideré relevante incluir el código directamente (resta más de lo que aporta).

Comment: Cámbia la línea `x = 'valor diferente'` por `x = 'val'` y obtendrás resultados diferentes. Por tanto no se puede concluir de ese benchmark que != sea ~3.6% más rápido. Los tres tardan lo mismo. Cualquier diferencia observada es ruido o un detalle de implementación del compilador/intérprete que no es extrapolable al caso general.

Comment: @JoseAntonioDuraOlmos Fue probado antes de publicar y puesto en otro comentario: [demo](http://ideone.com/ASBsUi). Los 2 casos más lentos pueden intercambiarse en poco tiempo pero se estabilizan en pruebas más largas. Definitivamente el caso de `!=` no tarda lo mismo. El ruido que mencionás se introduce si no se intercalan los métodos y se prueba iterar sobre uno, luego sobre el otro.

Comment: Prueba con [esto](http://ideone.com/AvXaaA)

Comment: @JoseAntonioDuraOlmos En ese ejemplo no estás comparando los mismos valores entre los 3 métodos, ya que `x()` se evalúa diferente para cada uno.. Te dejo un ejemplo más [acá](http://ideone.com/TE9a39) de cómo comparar eficientemente a ambos. Si no estás de acuerdo, más allá del -1, corregilo en tu respuesta.

Comment: Sigamos en un [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/45236/benchmarks-en-python)

Answer (score 6):

## Tardan lo mismo los tres

## Hacer benchmarking no es fácil

Los tres hacen lo mismo desde el punto de vista del comportamiento observable. El compilador o el intérprete de python podría por tanto generar/ejecutar exáctamente el mismo código en los tres casos. En cuyo caso tardaría exáctamente lo mismo en ejecutar pues es el mismo código generado. Y las diferencias observables serían ruido.

Uno podría verse tentado a desensamblar el código generado y ver que es diferente en los tres casos. Pero las conclusiones obtenidas así serían solo aplicables a la versión de python con las que se han hecho las pruebas. No serían aplicables en general.

Observemos como usando dos métodos diferentes de ejecutar estas instrucciones obtenemos resultados diferentes. Consideremos el siguiente programa :

```
import time

def not_igual():
  if not x == 'val':
    x

def distinto():
  if x != 'val':
    x
    
def igual_else():
  if x == 'val':
    pass
  else:
    x
    
def test(tam):
 
 inicio = time.time()
 i = 0
 while (i<tam) :
   i = i + 1
 fin = time.time()
 vacio = fin-inicio
 
 inicio = time.time()
 i = 0
 while (i<tam) :
   not_igual()
   i = i + 1
 fin = time.time()
 print( 'Tiempo not ==  es ' + str(fin-inicio-vacio)  )

 inicio = time.time()
 i = 0
 while (i<tam) :
   distinto()
   i = i + 1
 fin = time.time()
 print( 'Tiempo !=      es ' + str(fin-inicio-vacio)  )
 
 inicio = time.time()
 i = 0
 while (i<tam) :
   igual_else()
   i = i + 1
 fin = time.time()
 print( 'Tiempo == else es ' + str(fin-inicio-vacio)  )

x='val'
test(10000000)
```

Al ejecutarlo con el intérprete de python estos son los resultados obtenidos :

```
jose2@HP-Negro:~/t$ python a.py
Tiempo not ==  es 1.71001195908
Tiempo !=      es 1.9246609211
Tiempo == else es 1.75712680817
```

Y si lo ejecuto varias veces obtengo resultados similares. Parece que el ganador es **not ==**.

Ahora lo compilo a C con cpython. Y el código C lo compilo a un binario ELF para linux que ejecuto :

```
jose2@HP-Negro:~/t$ gcc -O2 -I /usr/include/python3.5m -o a a.c -lpython3.5m -lpthread -lm -lutil -ldl
jose2@HP-Negro:~/t$ ./a
Tiempo not ==  es 0.6007065773010254
Tiempo !=      es 0.6298408508300781
Tiempo == else es 0.6232995986938477
jose2@HP-Negro:~/t$ ./a
Tiempo not ==  es 0.5901763439178467
Tiempo !=      es 0.6861095428466797
Tiempo == else es 0.6084094047546387
jose2@HP-Negro:~/t$ ./a
Tiempo not ==  es 0.6090543270111084
Tiempo !=      es 0.6182305812835693
Tiempo == else es 0.6077189445495605
```

Ahora unas veces gana uno y otras veces gana otro.

Pero no solo puedo obtener resultados distintos con entornos de ejecución distintos. Con el mismo entorno de ejecución los resultados pueden ser distintos en función de los datos de entrada. Cambiemos la línea `x='val'` por `x='xxx'` y volvamos a ejecutar con el intérprete :

```
jose2@HP-Negro:~/t$ gedit a.py
jose2@HP-Negro:~/t$ python a.py
Tiempo not ==  es 2.22967505455
Tiempo !=      es 2.49930405617
Tiempo == else es 2.18658304214
```

Ahora es **== else** el que gana. Y al ejectarlo varias veces este resultado se repite. Y lo estoy ejecutando con exáctamente el mismo sistema en el que antes el ganador era **not ==**, solo han cambiado los datos de entrada.

Y ninguno de los benchmarks anteriores es bueno. En todas las pruebas el valor de `x` es siempre el mismo de principio a fin de la prueba. Habría que probar también con datos aleatorios o, mejor aún, con datos obtenidos de una situación similar a la que se espera que se ejecute nuestro programa. Nos podemos encontrar con sorpresas como que [los datos ordenados se procesen más rápido que los aleatorios](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/146/por-qu%C3%A9-se-procesa-m%C3%A1s-r%C3%A1pido-un-array-ordenado-que-uno-desordenado); quitando así todo valor a un benchmark excesivamente sencillo como lo presentado anteriormente.

Answer (score 4):

Yo pienso que no es necesario comparar estos operadores de comparación para determinar si uno es mucho más eficiente que otro, básicamente debido a que el cálculo se realiza tan rápido que se hace casi imposible detectar una diferencia.

Sin embargo, a mi parecer si que hay diferencias al momento de realizar comparaciones con uno u otro.

En teoría, usar

```
x != z
```

es más eficiente que usar

```
not x == val
```

La razón principal es porque *!=* realiza directamente la comparación y pregunta si *x* es diferente de *z*. En cambio, *not x == z* realiza dos operaciones en vez de una, porque primero valida si *x* es igual a *z* y luego *niega* el resultado de esa operación.

Por otro lado, hay que tener en cuenta el contexto en el cual estamos haciendo la comparación, de hecho, de eso depende el uso del uno u otro.
Lo que quiero decir con esto es que hay veces en las que resulta mucho más claro leer e interpretar una fracción de código con el uso de *not* que con el uso de *!=*, un ejemplo:

```
valid = 1 > 2; // false
```

Me resulta más legible la siguiente linea de código:

```
if not valid:
  ...
```

que esta:

```
if valid != true:
  ...
```

Y ya que hablo sobre legibilidad de código, aconsejaría no hacer uso de  palabras reservadas como *pass* o *break* debido a que estas interrumpen el flujo de código de una manera un poco abrupta y dificulta la legibilidad del mismo, haciendo que este se vuelva complejo e incomprensible. Tanto así, que algunos lo consideran como [Código espaguetti](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%C3%B3digo_espagueti).

Comment: "*not x == z realiza dos operaciones*" <-- No es cierto. El código compilado resulta en la misma cantidad de instrucciones... Estoy totalmente de acuerdo con el resto.

Comment: De acuerdo, muchas gracias por la aclaración, lo dije en forma hipotética porque nunca he hecho tests para demostrarlo.

Comment: "not x == z realiza dos operaciones" <--- Sí es cierto. Hay o puede haber compiladores/intérpretes de python en que se generen dos operaciones y resulte en un código generado menos eficiente que "x!=z". No, no es cierto. Hay o puede haber compiladores de python en que se optimice el código generado y resulte exáctamente en el mismo que "x!=z". Con lo que es cierto o falso dependiendo del intérprete/compilador usado. No se puede afirmar que no sea cierto en general, ni que sí sea cierto en general.

Answer (score 2):

Las diferencias en tiempo que conseguí fueron extremadamente mínimas, usando el siguiente algoritmo:

```py
import time, array
#Las pruebas las realicé con cada una de las dos siguientes líneas:
#x,y = 'val','lav'
#x,y = 'va1','lav'

print (x,y)
t = array.array('d')
suma = 0

for j in range(0,100):
    ti = time.process_time()

    for i in range (0,100000):
        if x == 'val':    # not x == 'val'    # x != 'val'
            y = 'val'

    tf = time.process_time()

    dif = tf - ti
    t.append(dif)

    suma += dif

print ('Promedio = ', suma / 100)
```

El promedio estuvo entre 12 y 14 milésimas de segundo, con `if` `TRUE`; y entre 9 y 13 milisegundos, con `if` `FALSE`.

Las posiciones de más rápida a más lenta, fueron  las siguientes:

`if` `TRUE`

1. `if x == 'val'`
2. `if x != 'val'`
3. `if not x == 'val'`

`if` `FALSE`

1. `if x != 'val'`
2. `if not x == 'val'`
3. `if x == 'val'`

Comment: Al comparar en ejecuciones diferentes, los tiempos varían levemente según las condiciones del sistema en ese momento. Para comparar tiempos de ejecución, conviene siempre realizarlo dentro del mismo programa, e incluso intercalando una prueba con otra. De esa forma, [`x != 'val'` es más eficiente incluso cuando `x = 'val'`](http://ideone.com/ASBsUi).

Comment: Gracias por la aclaración y por tu código, se puede aprender mucho estudiándolo, y más para mí que estoy iniciando en **Python**. Así es, como dices, por eso implementé el array `t`, para reducir al máximo cualquier interferencia en la medición, pero mejorable si seguimos tu consejo. Mi conclusión tras varias pruebas, es que no existe puesto fijo para ninguna de las variantes, aunque es cierto que `!=`, generalmente aventaja al resto. Incluso si pruebas varias veces tu código verás que se intercambian las posiciones, por ejemplo: `ne-en-ee`, `en-ne-ee`, `ne-ee-en`

Comment: Una forma de corregirlo podría ser usando 3 arrays, y llamando a los 3 métodos, agregando el tiempo a cada array correspondiente, para luego sacar el promedio sobre cada uno. En cuanto a las pruebas, los 2 más lentos pueden interambiar el orden de vez en cuando debido a que no se están probando el suficiente tiempo para marcar diferencia, y se están probando por poco tiempo porque la página donde lo publiqué tiene un máximo de ejecución de 5 seg. Si se prueba con más tiempo, este comportamiento se estabiliza.

Answer (score 2):

Según el [**Modelo de Datos**](https://docs.python.org/3.5/reference/datamodel.html#object.__eq__) de Python, si una clase no implementa el método `__ne__`, se delega en el método `__eq__`. Por tanto se presupone más eficiente comprobar `a == b` que comprobar `a != b`.

Por otro lado, una comprobación `if not` es considerada una única operación atómica, por diseño, no por caprichos de la implementación del intérprete (como se sugiere en algún comentario), del mismo modo que se decidió que eran equivalentes las operaciones `not a is b` y `a is not b`.

Así pues, la respuesta correcta debería ser más eficiente `if not x == y`. Pero **ésto no es cierto con los tipos nativos python**, ya que suelen tener implementados todos los métodos del modelo de datos, además de estar mucho más optimizada su invocación en comparación con métodos creados por el usuario.

Mi consejo es no obsesionarse por el rendimiento ya que las mejoras vienen de otra parte, como que las variables a comparar sean locales (en lugar de usar globales) o que se combinen *expresiones generadoras* con las funciones [`any()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#any) o [`all()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#all) en lugar de los típicos bucles con algún `if`.

Answer (score 1):

Para mi parecer ambas son la misma funcion, ocurre que en la primera:

```
if not x == 'val':
```

Estas condicionando a negación la sentencia de la condicion, es decir, si NO se cumple que X sea igual a val entonces haga algo, corre el if, de lo contrario si SI se cumple que X sea VAL entonces haga otra cosa

en la segunda

```
if x != 'val':
```

Estas haciendo lo mismo pero dices:

Si X es diferente de VAL entonces haga algo, de lo contrario si X no es igual a VAL entonces haga otra cosa

me parece trabajar con el método de != diferente de. ya que no condicionas desde el inicio a negar toda la sentencia que esta en el IF

Adicional, leyendo sobre como trabaja python estos dos comparadores, el primero lo convierte a un booleano, porque?, porque hará la pregunta al objeto de "Se cumple la condicion logica o no?"

y la segunda le preguntara "Eres igual a este valor?"

En cuanto a tu ejemplo:

```
if x == 'val':
pass
else:
```

estas declarando si X es igual al Valor haga algo, el metodo a utilizar seria en base a tu necesidad.

para saber si el valor es igual a la variable para que entre al sistema, X == val

Answer (score 1):

Te voy a dar una respuesta no basada en desensamblado, ni análisis de tiempos...

**Como programador python, eso te da bastante igual**, el 99,99% de las veces. Es muy raro que algo así vaya a afectar a la velocidad de tu script. De hecho, es hasta perjudicial perder el tiempo en estas "micro-optimizaciones", ya que probablemente haya otras posibles mejoras a nivel algorítmico.

Incluso con operaciones más complejas, como concatenaciones de strings, lo que se gana normalmente es ínfimo.